# Explicit way to check whether a function was called from within the Window

Tags: javascript

Is there a more explicit way of checking whether a function was called from within Window than  `if (typeof this.value == "undefined")` 
in the code below?

So that it is apparent that I am checking against Window, something like: `if this.name === "Window"`.

```js
function get_caller() {
  if (typeof this.value == "undefined") {
    console.log('function get_caller called from window')
  }
  else {
    console.log('function get_caller called by button press')
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', get_caller)
get_caller()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Get caller</button>
```

Comment: What happens when somebody calls `get_caller.call({value: "I am not in window"})`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just check if `this` is `window`:

```js
function get_caller() {
  if (this === window) {
    console.log('function get_caller called from window')
  }
  else {
    console.log('function get_caller called by button press')
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', get_caller)
get_caller()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Get caller</button>
```

Comment: Or `undefined`, in strict mode, which is the more common case today with webpack/modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `this==window` or if strict mode is on check if `this` is `undefined`,

```js
function get_caller() {
"use strict";    // !this is used for strict mode check
 if (this == window || !this) {
    console.log('function get_caller called from window')
  }
  else {
    console.log('function get_caller called by button press')
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', get_caller)
get_caller()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Get caller</button>
```